# Deleting a single ActiveStorage attachment out of a collection via an API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

EDIT: **TLDR**: This boils down to serializing the attachments. See my response.

I can see two ways to achieve this:

(1) Serialize the attachments (with `id` and `url` attributes), thus providing an `id` to the FE that they can use to `DELETE /attachments/:id` which would then call `ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(:id).purge`. The problem is with serializing as attachments do not have built-in models. I tried creating an `ActiveStorageAttachment` model for the `active_storage_attachments` table but  could not get the url for the attachment as the `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(@object)` requires an `ActiveStorage::Attachment` object not an `ActiveStorageAttachment` object.

(2) Another option would be to have a `DELETE /attachments/:attachment_url` endpoint. For this to work, I'd need to get the `ActiveStorage::Attachment` object based on the url, in order to call `purge` on it. Not sure if that is possible?

I'd much prefer the first solution, it feels cleaner and more adaptable. Any help with either approach would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is attachments connected to a model?

Comment: Here is an example:
`class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to serialize the attached images (option(1) above) using the `jsonapi-rb` gem.

In the controller, I `include: :images` and pass in the attachment type using the `expose` option:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
...
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render jsonapi: @post, include: :images, expose: {attachment_type: "images"} }
    end
  end
end
```

ActiveSupport gives you the `post.images_attachments` method for free:

```
class SerializablePost < JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource
  type 'posts'
  ...
  has_many :images do
    @object.images_attachments
  end
end
```

I created an attachment serializer:

```
class SerializableAttachment < JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  type do
    @attachment_type
  end
  attribute :id
  attribute :url do 
    url_for(@object)
  end
end
```

I needed to tell jsonapi to use this serializer for all attachments:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
...
  def jsonapi_class
    super.merge(
      'ActiveStorage::Attachment': SerializableAttachment
    )
  end
end
```

Now I can implement `DELETE /attachments/:id`.